# maxLength feature in beanio mapping file is not working

Tags: java, xml, database, bean-io

I have a requirement where I need to write a field value onto file with max length as 25. From DB I am getting length as 30. I am using 'maxLength=25' attribute in beanio mapping file.It somehow is still allowing value with length greater than 25. Anyone can suggest any solution or workaround for same?

Comment: Are you writing to a delimited format or fixed length format? Can you give us some example code demonstrating the problem, especially your `mapping.xml` file or the classes with annotations?

Comment: I have modified a small project to be fixed length format and it is working as expected. Show us what you have done and then we can help you

Comment: Below is the mapping.xml. For firstName i want that length should not exceed 25. yes I am writing to delimited format                  
<!-- language: xml --><stream name="DailyCasesSndStream" format="delimited" strict="true">
 <parser>  
     <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
   </parser>
  <record name="DailyCasesRecord"
   class="com.run.daily.batch.util.DailyCasesRecord"
   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
   <field name="firstName" maxLength="25" />
   <field name="midName" maxLength="25" />
  </record>
 </stream>
</beanio>

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to force BeanIO validations when writing (marshalling) objects to an `OutputStream` for **delimited** formats from my understanding of the documentation, according to [Section 4.6.2 Field Validation](http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#FieldValidation%20Field%20Validation). Emphasis mine.

> 4.6.2. Field Validation
>
> BeanIO supports several common field validation rules when reading an
>   input stream. All field validation rules are validated against the
>   field text before type conversion. When field trimming is enabled,
>   trim="true", all validations are performed after the field's text has
>   first been trimmed. **Field validations are ignored when writing to an
>   output stream.**

I guess it is working for fixed length formats otherwise you would have an invalid record (although the same argument probably applies to any format)

You have 2 options here:

1. Enforce the maximum length in your setter and/or getter methods if you want to be paranoid. This will affect your entire application (although I think it is a good idea to ensure your data consistency). You could do this in various ways and with the help of libraries (Apache Commons Lang's `StringUtils` come to mind). I'm leaving out any `null` checks, which you should take care of when using these approaches.

   ```
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName.substring(0, 25); // this should really not be necessary if you use the setter
   }

   public void setFirstName(final String newFirstName) {
     firstName = newFirstName.substring(0, 25);
   }
   ```

   This would not require any changes in your `mapping.xml` file.
2. Enforce the maximum length in an alternative setter and/or getter methods used explicitly by BeanIO for writing (marshalling) your data. Your getter/setter methods then don't do anything special and you add a new getter/setter pair per field. You could use just a  custom getter method when you only want to enforce the length when writing the data.

   ```
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName; 
   }

   public void setFirstName(final String newFirstName) {
     firstName = newFirstName;
   }

   // the BeanIO specific getter/setter
   public String getFirstNameBIO() {
     return firstName.substring(0, 25);
   }

   public void setFirstNameBIO(final String newFirstName) {
     firstName = newFirstName.substring(0, 25);
   }
   ```

   This would also require changes in your `mapping.xml` file.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">

     <stream name="DailyCasesSndStream" format="delimited" strict="true">
       <parser>
         <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
       </parser>
       <record name="DailyCasesRecord" class="com.run.daily.batch.util.DailyCasesRecord" minOccurs="0"
               maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <field name="firstName" maxLength="25" getter="getFirstNameBIO" setter="setFirstNameBIO"/>
         <!-- OR if you only want the new getter to be used -->
         <field name="midName" maxLength="25" getter="getMidNameBIO"/>
       </record>
     </stream>
   </beanio>
   ```

   Using this test code:

   ```
   final DailyCasesRecord dailyCasesRecord = new DailyCasesRecord();
   dailyCasesRecord.setFirstName("FirstNameFirstNameFirstName");
   dailyCasesRecord.setMidNameBIO("MidNameMidNameMidNameMidName");

   final StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
   factory.loadResource("mapping.xml");
   BeanWriter beanWriter = null;
   try (final StringWriter out = new StringWriter()) {
     beanWriter = factory.createWriter("DailyCasesSndStream", out);
     beanWriter.write(dailyCasesRecord);
     System.out.println(out.toString());
   } catch (final Exception e) {
     System.err.println(e.getMessage());
   } finally {
     if (beanWriter != null) {
       beanWriter.close();
     }
   }
   ```

   I get this output:

   ```
   FirstNameFirstNameFirstNa|MidNameMidNameMidNameMidN
   ```